# How to get the first letter from custom field?

Tags: php, custom-field

I have a custom field 'first_name' created by ACF advanced custom fields.
I use this code to get the value from the field:

the out put would be something like Mark.
What I need exactly is getting only the first letter from the first name.
I tried to use

```
$string = the_field('first_name');
echo $string[0];
```

&

```
$string = the_field('first_name');
echo substr($string, 0, 1);
```

&

```
$myStr = the_field('first_name'); 
$result = substr($myStr, 0, 1); 
echo $result;
```

but both methods give the full name not only the first letter.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
<?php

$string = get_field('first_name');
echo $string[0];

?>
```

I am not that much familiar with ACF. But my answer is based on their function reference here http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Hope this helps.

Sabbir H

Comment: More explaination about this: `the_field()` will echo field content while `get_field()` will return field content for further use :)

Comment: I am glad that it worked.